# Specifically search for gang hideouts

Tags: watch-dogs

I just started playing watch_dogs and the side quests I enjoy the most are gang hideouts. So I asked myself if there's any other way (than hacking random people and waiting until a gang hideout mission starts) to specifically search/start these missions (for example over a menu in my smartphone or elsewhere)?

Comment: There are only 20 of them.  In order to discover all of them you will need to unlock all the ctOS centers clearly.

Comment: I think there is only 15 actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to specifically search for gang hideouts. Hack ctOS centers and towers and hope thatremote profiling will reveal a gang hideout, or hack pedestrians and hope they will reveal a gang hideout.